# Compute $d(0,B)$ where $B=\{f\in \mathcal C([0,1])\mid f(0)=0, \int_0^1 f=1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(\mathcal C([0,1]),\|\cdot \|_\infty )$ the normed space where $\|\cdot \|_\infty $ is the supremum norm.

1) Compute $$d(0,B):=\inf_{\substack{f\neq 0 \\ f\in B}}d(0,f)$$ where $$B=\left\{f\in \mathcal C([0,1])\mid f(0)=0\text{ and } \int_0^1 f=1\right\}.$$

2) Is there $f\in B$ s.t. $d(0,B)=\|f\|_\infty $ ?

**Attempt**

1) The only thing I know is that if $f\in B$, then $$1=\int_0^1 f\leq \int_0^1 |f|\leq \|f\|_\infty,$$
and thus $d(0,B)\geq 1$. I guess the norm it $1$, but I can't find a sequence $(f_n)$ in $B$ s.t. $\|f_n\|_\infty \to 1$.

2) No idea.

Comment: If $f\in E$ then $\int_0^1f(x)dx=1$. What is the condition for $f(0)$?

Comment: Sorry, I edited f(0)=0

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_n\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}n\left(x-1+\frac1n\right)&\text{ if }x>1-\frac1n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Prove that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f_n\in B$ and compute $d(0,f_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

1) Take $$g_n=\begin{cases}
na_n x& x\in [0,1/n]\\
a_n&x\in [1/n,1]
\end{cases}.$$
It's a sequence of $B$ s.t. $\|g_n\|_\infty \to 1$. Therefore, $d(0,B)\leq 1$ and thus $d(0,B)=1$.

2) Suppose there is $f\in B$ s.t. $1=d(0,B)=\|f\|_\infty $. Then $$0\leq \int_0^1 (\|f\|_\infty -f)=\|f\|_\infty -\int_0^1 f=1-1=0.$$
Since $\|f\|_\infty -f$ is continuous and non negative, we get $\|f\|_\infty -f=0$ and thus $f=\|f\|_\infty $. Since $f(0)=0$, we get that $f\equiv 0$ and thus $f\notin B$.

Comment: You have the same inequality twice, you mean to flip one, no?

Comment: I corrected it, thank you @JuliusL33t